# how can i take return data in ajax jquery call c#.net?

Tags: jquery

I am a learner in jquery.
Can anyone help me for this code.

```
 function login() {
            FB.api('/me?fields=name,email', function (response) {

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Login.aspx/SaveFacebookAutoSignUp",
                        data: "{ 'Name':'" + rows[0].name + "', 'EmailId': '" + rows[0].email +"'}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            alert("You have successfully sign in.");

                        }
                    });

                });
            });
        }
```

Above call is made for "SaveFacebookAutoSignUp()" function in my code behind file.

this function returns user id in string format.

Can any one help me how to handle (get) return value from the function in jquery to handle more
action in my page.

Answer (score 1):

a simple way to da

```
function login() {
        FB.api('/me?fields=name,email', function (response) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Login.aspx/SaveFacebookAutoSignUp",
                    data: "{ 'Name':'" + rows[0].name + "', 'EmailId': '" + rows[0].email +"'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.d);

                    }
                });

            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: replace rows[0].name --> response.name and so on